# How to save all child component by clicking on save in parent component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a parent component which has multiple child component, I am passing one of the parent function as a props to child to so that when the data is changed in the child the same is been updated in the use variable present in parent component. However doing this is not accurately updating the correct details in my parent component. Can any one please let me know why the incorrect data is getting saved in the parent component?

```
//Parent component 

function updateSaveRequestCallBack(key,value){    
    switch(key){   
      case 'employeeName': setEmployeName(value);
      case 'emplId': setEmplyID(value);        
      case 'isCityizen': setNational(value);

.
.
.
etc i have like this some 10 to 15 fields
      default:
    }
  }
```

// in child i have some 10 to 15 controls

which will call the parent updateSaveRequestCallBack method and update the state variable present in the parent.

```
<text aria-required="true" id="employeeName" value={employeeName} 
                onChange={e.target.value=> { setCountryOption(e.target.value);props.updateSaveRequestCallBack('employeeName',e.target.value)}} />
```

At last when the user clicks the save button in the parent component.

All the values will be messed up and incorrect data is getting saved. My Save Handle is something like below.

```
function HandleSaveRequest() {    
    
      let saveRequestCommand = {
      employeeName:employeeName,
      employeeGender:employeeGender,
      DOB:DOB,
.
.
.
.
.
etc some 15 fields
  }
```

The data is getting messed up for the radio and select controls as they seems to be not accurate when the object is created before sending to the post api.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the switch statement. I missed to add the break statement